# Multiple php's $_SESSION variables from the same ip

Tags: php, session

If I open a new window in a browser, from the same computer I opened the last one, will it set up a new empty $_SESSION or will it use the one created by the last script I ran on this computer? Of-course both browser windows are running the same script..

If not, how can I do that?

If I work on two different browsers, will they share the session?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Windows (or Tabs) will use the same session.

You can prevent this by using the 'Private browsing' or 'Incognito' mode in newer Browsers. This will get you a fresh environment every time.

If you are on OSX, I can recommend Stainless (http://www.stainlessapp.com/) which uses the webkit engine and handles individual sessions within different tabs (See application preferences)

Comment: And what if I do it in a new browser? For example IE and chrome. will they share the session?

Comment: No, they will have different sessions as well.

Answer (score 2):

That depends. How are you handling the session id? Via the URL or cookies? If via cookies, are you setting them to live only until the browser closes, or until a certain time, or until a certain future time?

Comment: I'm not really handling the session id, just using what php does by default. What should I attempt to do if I want each browser window to have a different $_SESSION variable?

Comment: Nothing special. I believe the default for PHP is to use cookies and to live until the browser closes. You can double check that by looking for a PHPSESSID cookie in your browser (I prefer the FireCookie extension for Firebug for cookie analysis). If somehow the cookie is not set like that, then you're pretty much stuck to changing your PHP settings for that. So long as the browser still has the same session id, there's no way to distinguish one user from another.

Answer (score 1):

It will use the same session. Opening a new window is for the server the same as you would open it in the original window.